# What is useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig in the @Api / @ApiClass annotations of Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

When looking at the [Javadoc for @com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Api) of Google Cloud Endpoints Java annotations, I found a property that is not documented anywhere : [useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/javadoc/com/google/api/server/spi/config/Api#useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig()).

It looks like it provides a way to override Cloud Endpoints configuration from the datastore, but I did not find how to use it.

Does anyone know if it works and how it works ?

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like it provides a way to override Cloud Endpoints
>   configuration from the datastore, but I did not find how to use it.

Yes you can override Cloud Endpoints configuration. It is possible to override settings like OAuth client ids, scopes and audiences.

> Does anyone know if it works and how it works ?

The good news is it works!

1. In you @Api annotation enable the property useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig. Like this:

   @Api(name = "myapi", version = "v1", authLevel = AuthLevel.REQUIRED,
     clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
     scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE}, **useDatastoreForAdditionalConfig = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE**)
2. Create a new kind on Datastore named GoogleCloudEndpointConfiguration. It must have the properties (typed as String or List) clientIds, scopes and audiences. Example of this entity written in Java and using Objectify.

   @Entity
     public class GoogleCloudEndpointConfiguration extends BaseEntity {

   ```
   @Id
   private String className;

   private List<String> clientIds;

   private List<String> scopes;

   private List<String> audiences;
   ```

   ...
     }
3. For each endpoint you want to configure, add an entity on that kind with its id being its class name (with package).